# Which is correct: "[..] make the full overall list." or "[..] make up the full overall list." or "[..] make the full overall list up."?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

Which is correct: "These ten sub-lists together make the full overall list." or "These ten sub-lists together make up the full overall list." or "These ten sub-lists together make the full overall list up."?

I'm not sure whether the phrasal verb (i.e., adding "up") is needed here, because I know that "to make up" also means "to invent".

I'm also not sure whether the "up", if it goes there, should be at the end or in between.

Update: The only  answerer is apparently not sure, so, any other answers?

Comment: bear in mind: make up = invent and make up=comprise. This list is made up of ten words. This list is comprised of ten words.

Comment: These ten sub-lists make up or comprise or constitute the full list.

Answer (score 0):

> These ten sub-lists together make **the** full overall list.

> These ten sub-lists together make **for the** full overall list.

The usage of the definite article or preposition "*for*" followed by the definite article is the correct usage (in this case).

As you said yourself, *make up*  would be ambiguous in this case. The last example sentence of yours is quite weird sounding.

> These ten sub-lists together **make the** full overall list **up**.

We do not use the adverb at the end of a sentence to mean something like *making something up/creating something.*

---

On a short note, I would also like to point out the usage of ***full*** and ***overall*** in the same sentence, back-to-back.

- **full** - complete, whole, or containing a lot of detail.
- **overall** - in general rather than in particular, or including all the people or things in a particular group or situation.

Both the adjectives defines something whole. So I would rather say you use only one of the two words: *full/overall*. You can also consider the following alternative:

> These ten sub-lists together make for the **whole** list.

---

**Edit**: According to original poster's comment, "make for the whole" is a rare instance (I did not get just four results though). It might be so, but it sounds the best in this case. [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=make%20for%20the%20whole%2Cmake%20up%20the%20whole&year_start=1700&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3#) showing the stable pace of "make for the whole" as against the rapid decrease in "make up the whole".

Comment: So, if I mean "to make" in the same sense that all the parts of something make (up?) that whole something,  "make for" is the correct expression? I just googled "together make for the whole" and it occurs just four times in the whole Internet.

Comment: @Philosopherofscience I have to do some more research on it. It seems a little bit tricky. Although I hardly think people will misinterpret even if you use "make up the whole". If any user down-votes it then I might delete my answer as well. Because I don't want to mislead fellow users.

Comment: But you still think that "make up the whole" is better than "make the whole" without "up", right?

Comment: @Philosopherofscience No, I don't think _make up the whole_ is better than _make the whole_. But I said (in my previous comment) that it might be acceptable by some people.

Comment: @Dhanishyha Ghosh So I'm confused about what I should do.